# JSON Export Type CSV in UI5 - Umlauts

Tags: json, csv, sapui5, export-to-csv, diacritics

I have a problem to convert umlauts like "äöü" in the .csv format (output is ä=Ã¤, ö=Ã¶, ü=Ã¼).
How i can convert my JSON Table in UTF-8 before i export my data to .csv to use it in Excel?
So i am export my data with JSON and the following code:

```
var oTable= sap.ui.getCore().byId("oTable");
                    var oTableJSON = oTable.getModel().getProperty("/");
                    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                
                
                oModel.setData(oTableJSON);

var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({
    exportType: new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
        separatorChar: ";",
        charSet: "UTF-8",
    }),
    models: oModel,

rows: {
    path: "/" 
},
columns: [
    {
        name: "First name",
        template: {
            content: {
                path: "firstname"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Last name",
        template: {
            content: {
                path: "lastname"
            }
        }
    }
]
});


oExport.saveFile().always(function() {
    this.destroy();
});
```

Output:

> ```
> First name;Last name
> Ã¤l;dente
> ```

https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/f1ee7a8b2102415bb0d34268046cd3ea

Comment: Is the issue still reproducible?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an issue with the binding path, so give the following code a try

```
rows: {
    path: "/data" 
}
```